# ¿Por qué no es válido colocar una respuesta de la misma persona que publicó una pregunta?

Tags: discusión

En una pregunta que respondí específicamente [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/21505/6635), podría no ser una respuesta que solvente el problema del usuario.

Mi inconveniente no es ese, sino lo que [comenta otro usuario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/21505/ir-a-otro-controlador-desde-javascript/21542?noredirect=1#comment34309_21542)

> Te recomiendo que no abras una respuesta a tu pregunta, es preferible que Edites tu Pregunta y coloque la respuesta si es que no encontraste una respuesta correcta entre las postuladas... Ahora si encontraste una respuesta entre las colocadas, elige la mejor respuesta para que esta sea una referencia en próximas preguntas. – Alfonso Carrasco.

Entonces comenté que no era aplicable ya que solventa el mismo su problema y por otro lado entendiendo que mi respuesta, tal vez no fue muy funcional. Y me vuelve a comentar

> yo creo que si porque su solución está basada en respuestas y trabajo colaborativo con otros participantes. Si no hubiera ninguna respuesta entonces aplica responder tu mismo tu pregunta, cuando encuentres la solución...

Aun así a pesar de que tubo ayuda en comentarios;
**¿Debería publicarse como respuesta ya que es la solución valida a su problema o debería editar su pregunta y colocar ahí su solución?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La sección de preguntas es para colocar el texto de la pregunta. Para las respuesta (incluso respuestas a tus propias preguntas) se utiliza la sección de respuestas. La respuesta que publicó el autor es completamente válida (no significa que sea una buena respuesta, eso lo decide la comunidad con los votos a favor/en contra).